# 'llvm-extract > llvm-link > clang' flow is not able to compile to binary

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, linker-errors, llvm-ir

**How to fix the fact that** `external hidden global` **and** `internal global` **declarations do not merge?**

I have been working on flow to extract a function from LLVM IR, link it back again and compile to binary. However, in the last step, the compilation from the Linked IR to binary fails with the following message:

```
/tmp/real-linked-fbcc7e.o: In function `__cxx_global_var_init':
real-linked.ll:(.text.startup+0x2fa): undefined reference to `std::__ioinit'
real-linked.ll:(.text.startup+0x313): undefined reference to `std::__ioinit'
/usr/bin/ld: out: hidden symbol `_ZStL8__ioinit' isn't defined
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My flow to extract and re-link the function `__cxx_global_var_init` goes as follows:

```
llvm-extract-4.0 -func __cxx_global_var_init original.ll -S -o extracted_f.ll
llvm-link-4.0 code01.ll -override extract_f.ll -S -o linked.ll
clang++-4.0 linked.ll -o out
```

Where:

- `__cxx_global_var_init` is the function to be extracted from `original.ll`;
- `original.ll` is the source file;
- `extracted_f.ll` is a file that contains only the function and declarations of its dependencies;
- `linked.ll` is the output file before compilation to binary
- `out` is the final binary

The undefined reference is declared on:

- `extracted_f.ll` as:

  - `@_ZStL8__ioinit=external hidden global %"class.std::ios_base::Init", align 1`
- `original.ll` as:

  - `@_ZStL8__ioinit = internal global %"class.std::ios_base::Init" zeroinitializer, align 1`
- `linked.ll` as:

  - `@_ZStL8__ioinit.6 = internal global %"class.std::allocator" zeroinitializer, align 1`
  - `@_ZStL8__ioinit = external hidden global %"class.std::allocator", align 1`

As you may suspect, the linked function on `linked.ll` calls the wrong version of the declared: `@_ZStL8__ioinit.6`.

---

**Questions:**

**Is there any command line option that I am missing?**

**Is there a way to replace the function using the declarations of the original file?**

---

NOTE:
I am able to re-link and compile functions with no calls to other functions.

Comment: Linking a static library only includes the symbols that are actually used, not all symbols in the library. Presumably, nothing in `code01.ll` made any reference to `std::__ioinit`. So that symbol was not included during the initial linkage. You should be able to resolve this by re-linking against libc++. (I'm not 100% sure, hence why this is a comment, not an answer)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I understand what you proposed, but I believe the problem lies on how my function dependencies were extracted. I just performed another test and deleting the keyword `hidden` from the extracted IR resolves the issue. But I still cannot find a way to do it automatically during extraction phase.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Removing the keyword before the linking DOES NOT fix my issue. And the only way to fix it, is reverting on the `linked.ll` file `@_ZStL8__ioinit = external hidden global %"class.std::allocator", align 1` to `@_ZStL8__ioinit = internal global %"class.std::ios_base::Init" zeroinitializer, align 1`. Is there any command line I can run with clang that can help me debug the process?